# Google Web Fonts looking inproperly on Konqueror - bold∧italic

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I've recently applied the Arimo font from Google Web Fonts. On almost all modern browsers it looks [normally](http://wstaw.org/m/2013/03/28/plasma-desktopIvC633.png) but in Konqueror (KDE 4.10.1) all fonts are [bold and italic](http://wstaw.org/m/2013/03/28/plasma-desktopKPS633.png).

Are there any hacks, or solutions to prevent this behavior?

My `<link>` to the font is:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just externally define `font-style: normal !important;` and `font-weight: normal !important;` in the css where you are seeing them `bold` and `italic` in `Konqueror`. So it will behave same in all the browsers.

Comment: @Rapidwolf you need to bug the css that from where it is taking it as bold and italic. That will only help you if you are saying you tried this. Why don't you define the css as `!important` so it will not take css from anywhere else and will use your's

Comment: Check my updated answer and try adding `!important` in the `CSS`